# convert binary to file p12 in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, ssl-certificate, pkcs#12

I get in one api a certificate digital with this value so:

[response api imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2V5a.png)

I need convert this value to a physical file on Android device any folder how extension **.p12**
for after upload from the app.
finally read the file with next function FileInputStream:

```
    try {
        KeyStore p12 = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
        p12.load(new FileInputStream(filepath), etPassword.getText().toString().toCharArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

any help thank you very much

Comment: If you can read a file then what is the problem writing such a file?

Comment: or can say how to match the string for function *new FileInputStream(/*string long*/)* ?  without convert to file physical